# Gamma function in terms of a linear function

Tags: gamma-function

I have noticed that the plot of the function $[\Gamma(x+1)]^{1/x}$ for $x > 0$ looks like a straight line at all scales. This implies that $\Gamma(x+1) \approx ((1-e^{-\gamma})x+e^{-\gamma})^x$ for $x>0$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler--Mascheroni constant. Does anybody please know how to substantiate this?

Comment: Well numerically the Maclaurin series is not very close to a linear function: $\Gamma(1+x)^{\frac1x}\approx.561+.462x-.035x^2+.019x^3-.012x^4+.008x^5$...

Comment: (btw the linear term is $\frac{\pi^2}{12}e^{-\gamma}$ rather than $1-e^{-\gamma}$)

Comment: Numerically, $\lim \frac{\Gamma(x+1)^{1/x}-x}{1-x}= e^{-c}$ with $c\approx .4586757$ instead of $\gamma$.

Comment: The slope of the function goes down from approximately 0.461 (not 0.561) to approximately 0.368 at infinity. So it is not constant, but may look close to constant on a plot.

Comment: $ {\ln(\Gamma(1+x)) \over  x} \approx -\gamma + \zeta(2)/2 x - \zeta(3)/3 x^2 + ... $ So also the exponential of the ratio shouldn't be too much linear...

Comment: @MichaelRenardy If you have in mind "my" numbers it is in accordance with them: .561 is the constant term, initial slope at 0 is about .462

Comment: Note that for my limit, it might be $\lim \frac{\Gamma(x+1)^{1/x}-x}{1-x}=1-\frac1e$, which would make $c=.458675145387...$ (don't worry too much about my last decimal in the preceding comment). Thus we would have equivalently $\boxed{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{x-1}{\Gamma(x+1)^{1/x}-1}=e}$. That looks so nice that it might almost be obtained from Stirling's formula (?)

Comment: And in fact it trivially does indeed, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/247434/is-this-asymptotic-of-the-gamma-function-true